# What is the decorator running order?

Tags: typescript, decorator

I don't understand why the result is "directive before component".

```
function Component(component) {
    console.log('selector: ' + component.selector);
    console.log('template: ' + component.template);
    console.log('component init');
    return (target: any) => {
        console.log('component call');
        return target;
    }
}

function Directive() {
    console.log('directive init');
    return (target: any) => {
        console.log('directive call');
        return target;
    }

}

@Component({selector: 'person',template: 'person.html'})
@Directive()
class Person {}

let p = new Person();
```

Output:

```
selector: person
template: person.html
component init
directive init
directive call
component call
```

Shouldn't the `component call` be before `directive call`?

Comment: Why do you think that? Decorators apply to the thing below them, so are applied "inside out".

Comment: I read it from somewhere, decorator runs from left to right, from top to down

Comment: This is directly covered in the manual https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-composition

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The decorator *expressions* get called top to bottom, and produce decorators.

The decorators *themselves* run in the opposite direction, bottom to top:

```
@a @b x
// bit like
{
  const decA = a
  const decB = b
  decA(decB(x))
}
```

In your example

```
{
  const decComp = Component({selector: 'person', template: 'person.html'})
  // selector: person
  // template: person.html
  // component init
  const decDirective = Directive()
  // directive init
  decComp(decDirective(Person))
  // directive call
  // component call
}
```

[Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)

Answer (score 8):

> Shouldn't the component call be before directive call?

No. Inner will get called before outer. Essentially

```
@C
@D
class Person {}
```

Becomes *something* akin to:

```
C(D(class Person()))
```